# Column formatting directive string in Kendo Grid / Angular 2+

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I've seen some examples of using a string to tell a Kendo column how to format some data. See here - http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-format. I'm wondering if there's any documentation on these strings, as I haven't been able to find anything. Specifically, I need to be able to change the currency symbol depending on the incoming data. Also do dates need to be JavaScript date objects in order to be formatted?